# Get value of SelectedIndex in a dynamically created RadioButtonList added to a dynamically created table

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I have an array of `RadioButtonList`s.

```
RadioButtonList[] r = new RadioButtonList[20];
```

On clicking a view button, my program creates a dynamic table and adds an image and a `RadioButtonList` to each cell:

```
tcell.Controls.Add(r[i])
```

On clicking a submit button, I’m trying to access the value of `SelectedIndex` on all `RadioButtonList`s; however, it’s showing up as `null`.

```
var value = r[i].SelectedValue;
```

I found some answers on how to get the value of `RadioButton`s created dynamically using `.FindControl`, but since my table is also dynamic, when I give `Table1.rows`, it results in `null`.

Comment: `tcell.Add.Controls.(r[i])` isn’t a thing.

Comment: What are you working in? WinForms? WPF? Xamarin?

Comment: Is this ASP.NET?

Comment: Yes this is Asp.net , i am creating a website

Comment: @yoona you should include that as a tag, when we just see C# that can mean so many different things.  Especially when you are using classes specific to a toolkit.

Comment: @Ryan , I am sorry , it is tcell.Controls.Add(r[i])

Comment: @yoona I may be wrong here but I believe you want to use the WebForms tag instead of the website

Answer (score 1):

Dynamically created controls lose their state, when they are posted back, so you will have to re-create it yourself - outside the

`if(!IsPostBack)`

block in `Page_Load` (or somewhere similar).